# Eventloop has high ksoftirqd load; nginx does not but does same system-calls. Why?

Tags: c, linux, performance, epoll, event-loop

I wrote some code that has an epoll-eventloop, accepts new connections and pretends to be a http-server.
The posted code is the absolute minimum ... I removed everything (including all error-checks) to make it as short and to the point as possible:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main () {
    int servFd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_IP);
    int value = 1;
    setsockopt (servFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &value, sizeof (value));

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset (&servAddr, 0, sizeof (servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons (8081);
    bind (servFd, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof (servAddr));
    listen (servFd, 511);

    int efd = epoll_create1 (EPOLL_CLOEXEC);
    struct epoll_event epollEvt;
    epollEvt.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP;
    epollEvt.data.u32 = servFd;
    epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, servFd, &epollEvt);

    for (;;) {
        struct epoll_event pollEvent[512];
        int eventCount = epoll_wait (efd, pollEvent, 512, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < eventCount; ++i) {
            struct epoll_event* curEvent = &pollEvent[i];
            if (curEvent->data.u32 == servFd) {
                int clientFd = accept4 (servFd, NULL, NULL, SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC);
                struct epoll_event epollEvt;
                epollEvt.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLET;
                epollEvt.data.u32 = clientFd;
                epoll_ctl (efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, clientFd, &epollEvt);
                continue;
            }

            int clientFd = curEvent->data.u32;
            char recvBuffer[2048];
            recvfrom (clientFd, recvBuffer, 2048, 0, NULL, NULL);
            char sndMsg[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: nginx/1.12.2\r\nDate: Tue, 10 Apr 2018 17:41:57 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
            size_t sndMsgLength = sizeof (sndMsg) - 1;
            struct iovec sndBuffer;
            sndBuffer.iov_base = sndMsg;
            sndBuffer.iov_len = sndMsgLength;
            writev (clientFd, &sndBuffer, 1);
            close (clientFd);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
localhost:~# gcc -Wall -O2 test.c -o test
```

---

```
localhost:~# gcc --version
gcc (Alpine 6.4.0) 6.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

I did some load-testing of this code and compared it with nginx to see if I did something wrong or if there is something to improve. I expected this code to be the fastest possible implementation since every other "real" webserver has to do a lot more stuff in userspace. But still ... somehow nginx beats it in requests per second when using multiple load-generator threads. (Note that I configured nginx to use just one worker to handle every request)

```
//ab running 1 worker from local machine 
localhost:~# ab -n 100000 -c 1 http://10.0.0.111:8081/index.html
Requests per second:    13228.07 [#/sec] (mean)  //[to nginx]
Requests per second:    15300.35 [#/sec] (mean)  //[to testcode]
//ab running 4 worker from local machine 
localhost:~# ab -n 100000 -c 4 http://10.0.0.111:8081/index.html
Requests per second:    30902.63 [#/sec] (mean)  //[to nginx]
Requests per second:    24734.76 [#/sec] (mean)  //[to testcode]
```

The first test has the expected result ... the test code is faster since it doesn't do anything except generating a hard-coded response. But why is nginx faster in a multi-threading setting? How can that be? 
The only explanation I can come up with is that there is something different in kernel-space and that nginx uses some sockopts (like TCP_FASTOPEN or TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT) or maybe some other system-calls to do its thing. Thats why I did some straces and made my code do the exact same thing as nginx does (from a kernel-perspective) --> you can see the strace attached below. Still ... it is faster and I don't understand why.

```
//ab running 50 worker from remote machine 
localhost:~# ab -n 100000 -c 50 http://10.0.0.111:8081/index.html
Requests per second:    27507.60 [#/sec] (mean)  //[to nginx]
Requests per second:    24208.51 [#/sec] (mean)  //[to testcode]
```

This test-cast has the exact same result but I noticed some difference in CPU-usage.

- My test-code runs at about 60% CPU-load and ksoftirqd/0 runs at about 80%
- nginx runs at about 99% CPU-load and ksoftirqd/0 runs at just 30%
- ksoftirqd/0 has no noticeable CPU-load in the local-host setting in both cases

---

sTrace of nginx:

```
localhost:~# strace -tt -f /usr/sbin/nginx 
//Removed loading of libraries to stay under the 30k char body limit for this question
13:28:20.426369 open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
13:28:20.426549 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=127, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.426723 mmap(NULL, 127, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x74ae1cf8c000
13:28:20.426847 close(3)                = 0
13:28:20.427023 getpid()                = 2186
13:28:20.427164 open("/var/lib/nginx/logs/error.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 3
13:28:20.427341 brk(0xd104603e000)      = 0xd104603e000
13:28:20.427503 open("/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 4
13:28:20.427680 brk(0xd104603f000)      = 0xd104603f000
13:28:20.427819 readv(4, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="[ req ]\n#default_bits\t\t= 2048\n#d"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 745
13:28:20.428089 brk(0xd1046040000)      = 0xd1046040000
13:28:20.428243 readv(4, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=1024}], 2) = 0
13:28:20.428476 close(4)                = 0
13:28:20.428718 brk(0xd1046041000)      = 0xd1046041000
13:28:20.428880 brk(0xd1046042000)      = 0xd1046042000
13:28:20.429179 brk(0xd1046043000)      = 0xd1046043000
13:28:20.429319 brk(0xd1046044000)      = 0xd1046044000
13:28:20.429552 brk(0xd1046045000)      = 0xd1046045000
13:28:20.429775 brk(0xd1046046000)      = 0xd1046046000
13:28:20.429935 brk(0xd1046047000)      = 0xd1046047000
13:28:20.430220 brk(0xd1046048000)      = 0xd1046048000
13:28:20.430391 brk(0xd1046049000)      = 0xd1046049000
13:28:20.430515 brk(0xd104604b000)      = 0xd104604b000
13:28:20.430796 brk(0xd104604c000)      = 0xd104604c000
13:28:20.431042 brk(0xd104604d000)      = 0xd104604d000
13:28:20.431238 brk(0xd104604e000)      = 0xd104604e000
13:28:20.431396 brk(0xd104604f000)      = 0xd104604f000
13:28:20.431581 brk(0xd1046050000)      = 0xd1046050000
13:28:20.431820 brk(0xd1046051000)      = 0xd1046051000
13:28:20.432112 brk(0xd1046054000)      = 0xd1046054000
13:28:20.432374 brk(0xd1046055000)      = 0xd1046055000
13:28:20.432509 brk(0xd1046056000)      = 0xd1046056000
13:28:20.432666 brk(0xd1046057000)      = 0xd1046057000
13:28:20.432836 brk(0xd1046058000)      = 0xd1046058000
13:28:20.433004 brk(0xd1046059000)      = 0xd1046059000
13:28:20.433203 brk(0xd104605a000)      = 0xd104605a000
13:28:20.433400 brk(0xd104605b000)      = 0xd104605b000
13:28:20.433610 brk(0xd104605c000)      = 0xd104605c000
13:28:20.433740 brk(0xd104605d000)      = 0xd104605d000
13:28:20.433895 brk(0xd104605e000)      = 0xd104605e000
13:28:20.434020 brk(0xd104605f000)      = 0xd104605f000
13:28:20.434240 brk(0xd1046060000)      = 0xd1046060000
13:28:20.434419 brk(0xd1046061000)      = 0xd1046061000
13:28:20.434622 uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="localhost", ...}) = 0
13:28:20.434801 sched_getaffinity(0, 128, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) = 32
13:28:20.435077 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=4*1024}) = 0
13:28:20.435260 brk(0xd1046066000)      = 0xd1046066000
13:28:20.435424 uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="localhost", ...}) = 0
13:28:20.435578 brk(0xd104606b000)      = 0xd104606b000
13:28:20.435700 open("/etc/nginx/nginx.conf", O_RDONLY) = 4
13:28:20.435912 fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2781, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.436115 pread64(4, "\n\n\nuser nginx;\npcre_jit on;\n#tim"..., 2781, 0) = 2781
13:28:20.436284 geteuid()               = 0
13:28:20.436440 open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
13:28:20.436596 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.436725 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.436857 readv(5, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/ash\nb"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 1024
13:28:20.437047 readv(5, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="sbin/nologin\nntp:x:123:123:NTP:/"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 397
13:28:20.437235 lseek(5, -43, SEEK_CUR) = 1378
13:28:20.437353 close(5)                = 0
13:28:20.437520 open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
13:28:20.437684 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.437800 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.437933 readv(5, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="root:x:0:root\nbin:x:1:root,bin,d"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 776
13:28:20.438097 close(5)                = 0
13:28:20.438240 epoll_create1(0)        = 5
13:28:20.438429 close(5)                = 0
13:28:20.438681 brk(0xd1046070000)      = 0xd1046070000
13:28:20.438842 brk(0xd1046072000)      = 0xd1046072000
13:28:20.439053 brk(0xd1046074000)      = 0xd1046074000
13:28:20.439175 brk(0xd1046076000)      = 0xd1046076000
13:28:20.439418 brk(0xd104607b000)      = 0xd104607b000
13:28:20.439655 mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74ae1ce8b000
13:28:20.439886 brk(0xd1046080000)      = 0xd1046080000
13:28:20.440020 brk(0xd1046085000)      = 0xd1046085000
13:28:20.440225 open("/etc/nginx/mime.types", O_RDONLY) = 5
13:28:20.440380 fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3957, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.440523 pread64(5, "\ntypes {\n    text/html          "..., 3957, 0) = 3957
13:28:20.440725 close(5)                = 0
13:28:20.440977 brk(0xd104608a000)      = 0xd104608a000
13:28:20.441297 brk(0xd104608c000)      = 0xd104608c000
13:28:20.441453 close(4)                = 0
13:28:20.441587 mkdir("/var/tmp/nginx/client_body", 0700) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
13:28:20.441814 stat("/var/tmp/nginx/client_body", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.442022 mkdir("/var/tmp/nginx/proxy", 0700) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
13:28:20.442149 stat("/var/tmp/nginx/proxy", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.442257 mkdir("/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi", 0700) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
13:28:20.442407 stat("/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.442568 mkdir("/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi", 0700) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
13:28:20.442732 stat("/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.442945 mkdir("/var/tmp/nginx/scgi", 0700) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
13:28:20.443051 stat("/var/tmp/nginx/scgi", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
13:28:20.443229 open("/var/log/nginx/access.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 4
13:28:20.443417 fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.443586 open("/var/log/nginx/error.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 5
13:28:20.443750 fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.443889 open("/var/lib/nginx/logs/error.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 6
13:28:20.444040 fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.444197 mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74ae1c0a0000
13:28:20.444382 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 7
13:28:20.444515 setsockopt(7, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
13:28:20.444680 ioctl(7, FIONBIO, [1])  = 0
13:28:20.444808 bind(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8081), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
13:28:20.445015 listen(7, 511)          = 0
13:28:20.445140 listen(7, 511)          = 0
13:28:20.445326 mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74ae1ce7b000
13:28:20.445493 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=4*1024}) = 0
13:28:20.445671 mmap(NULL, 1280, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74ae1ce7a000
13:28:20.445817 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RT_1 RT_2], NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.445977 rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.446097 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.446247 rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.446438 rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.446635 rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.446886 rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.447093 rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.447236 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.447446 rt_sigaction(SIGIO, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.447767 rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0xd1041f1f3fc, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.447888 rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.448094 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x74ae1cd4a6cf}, NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.448253 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], [], 8) = 0
13:28:20.448396 fork(strace: Process 2187 attached
)                  = 2187
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.448594 gettid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  2186] 13:28:20.448643 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.448671 <... gettid resumed> ) = 2187
[pid  2186] 13:28:20.448700 <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.448765 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2186] 13:28:20.448792 exit_group(0 <unfinished ...>
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.448812 <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2186] 13:28:20.448836 <... exit_group resumed>) = ?
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.448854 getpid()    = 2187
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.448951 setsid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  2186] 13:28:20.449046 +++ exited with 0 +++
13:28:20.449055 <... setsid resumed> )  = 2187
13:28:20.449107 umask(000)              = 022
13:28:20.449212 open("/dev/null", O_RDWR) = 8
13:28:20.449309 dup2(8, 0)              = 0
13:28:20.449455 dup2(8, 1)              = 1
13:28:20.449573 close(8)                = 0
13:28:20.449692 open("/run/nginx/nginx.pid", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 8
13:28:20.449848 pwrite64(8, "2187\n", 5, 0) = 5
13:28:20.449978 close(8)                = 0
13:28:20.450111 dup2(6, 2)              = 2
13:28:20.450218 close(3)                = 0
13:28:20.450376 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], NULL, 8) = 0
13:28:20.450499 socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, [3, 8]) = 0
13:28:20.450603 ioctl(3, FIONBIO, [1])  = 0
13:28:20.450696 ioctl(8, FIONBIO, [1])  = 0
13:28:20.450830 ioctl(3, FIOASYNC, [1]) = 0
13:28:20.450964 fcntl(3, F_SETOWN, 2187) = 0
13:28:20.451079 fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.451148 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
13:28:20.451244 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], 8) = 0
13:28:20.451379 fork(strace: Process 2188 attached
 <unfinished ...>
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.451596 gettid( <unfinished ...>
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.451615 <... fork resumed> ) = 2188
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.451727 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO],  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.451754 <... gettid resumed> ) = 2188
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.451774 <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.451942 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO],  <unfinished ...>
[pid  2187] 13:28:20.451969 rt_sigsuspend([], 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.451985 <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.452053 getpid()    = 2188
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.452330 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.452621 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.452893 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=8*1024, rlim_max=8*1024}, NULL) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.453075 futex(0x74ae1cf95064, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.453279 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.453487 geteuid()   = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.453667 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.453861 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.454091 setgid(103) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.454335 futex(0x74ae1cf95064, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.454583 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.454822 socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 9
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.455183 connect(9, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 24) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.455537 close(9)    = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.455800 open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.456030 fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.456331 fcntl(9, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.456544 readv(9, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="root:x:0:root\nbin:x:1:root,bin,d"..., iov_len=1024}], 2) = 776
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.456799 readv(9, [{iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=1024}], 2) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.456956 close(9)    = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.457134 setgroups(3, [103, 82, 103]) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.457365 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.457534 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.457818 setuid(102) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.457990 futex(0x74ae1cf95064, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.458159 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [HUP INT QUIT USR1 USR2 ALRM TERM CHLD WINCH IO], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.458378 prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, SUID_DUMP_USER) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.458598 chdir("/var/www") = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.458868 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.459703 epoll_create1(0) = 9
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.459994 eventfd2(0, 0) = 10
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.460340 epoll_ctl(9, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 10, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLET, {u32=1109208384, u64=14363479846208}}) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.460600 eventfd2(0, 0) = 11
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.460878 ioctl(11, FIONBIO, [1]) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.461043 io_setup(32, [0x74ae1ce79000]) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.461389 epoll_ctl(9, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 11, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLET, {u32=1109208032, u64=14363479845856}}) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.461729 socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, [12, 13]) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.462043 epoll_ctl(9, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 12, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=1109208032, u64=14363479845856}}) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.462255 close(13)   = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.462608 epoll_pwait(9, [{EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP|EPOLLRDHUP, {u32=1109208032, u64=14363479845856}}], 1, 5000, NULL, 8) = 1
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.462969 close(12)   = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.463325 mmap(NULL, 987136, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74ae1bfaf000
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.463517 mmap(NULL, 397312, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74ae1ce18000
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.464039 mmap(NULL, 397312, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74ae1cdb7000
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.466039 epoll_ctl(9, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 7, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLRDHUP, {u32=469430304, u64=128291142561824}}) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.466432 close(3)    = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.466763 epoll_ctl(9, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 8, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLRDHUP, {u32=469430544, u64=128291142562064}}) = 0
//Eventloop starts here
[pid  2188] 13:28:20.467046 epoll_pwait(9, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=469430304, u64=128291142561824}}], 512, -1, NULL, 8) = 1
[pid  2188] 13:28:34.390021 accept4(7, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(54280), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.15")}, [112->16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 3
[pid  2188] 13:28:34.390110 epoll_ctl(9, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=469430784, u64=128291142562304}}) = 0
[pid  2188] 13:28:34.390188 epoll_pwait(9, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=469430784, u64=128291142562304}}], 512, 30000, NULL, 8) = 1
[pid  2188] 13:28:34.390245 recvfrom(3, "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: "..., 2048, 0, NULL, NULL) = 93
[pid  2188] 13:28:34.390462 writev(3, [{iov_base="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: nginx/1"..., iov_len=142}], 1) = 142
[pid  2188] 13:28:34.390602 close(3)    = 0
```

sTrace of the test-code:

```
localhost:/~# strace -tt -f ./test 
18:07:49.511351 execve("./test", ["./test"], 0x735df8f6c0a0 /* 16 vars */) = 0
18:07:49.514382 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x71a7644fdb88) = 0
18:07:49.515405 set_tid_address(0x71a7644fdbc0) = 2325
18:07:49.515983 mprotect(0x71a7644fa000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
18:07:49.516742 mprotect(0x322e536d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
18:07:49.517329 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
18:07:49.518692 setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
18:07:49.519955 bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8080), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
18:07:49.521092 listen(3, 511)          = 0
18:07:49.521764 epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC) = 4
18:07:49.522239 epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLRDHUP, {u32=3, u64=3}}) = 0
18:07:49.523392 epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=3, u64=3}}], 512, -1, NULL, 8) = 1
18:07:52.616270 accept4(3, NULL, NULL, SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 5
18:07:52.617149 epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 5, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=5, u64=5}}) = 0
18:07:52.618188 epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=5, u64=5}}], 512, -1, NULL, 8) = 1
18:07:52.619472 recvfrom(5, "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: "..., 2048, 0, NULL, NULL) = 93
18:07:52.620474 writev(5, [{iov_base="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: nginx/1.12"..., iov_len=142}], 1) = 142
18:07:52.622846 close(5)                = 0
```

Edit:
I did some more traceing ... 400000 request from a remote host ... still no clue why this happens:

```
localhost:/~# strace -c -f /usr/sbin/nginx 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 47.11    0.040309           0    400000           writev
 44.55    0.038115           0    400021           close
  3.11    0.002658           0    400002           accept4
  1.80    0.001538           0    400002           recvfrom
  1.74    0.001486           0    400007           epoll_ctl
  1.69    0.001450           0    400008           epoll_pwait

localhost:/~# strace -c -f ./test 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 47.90    0.042760           0    400002           writev
 44.27    0.039518           0    400002           close
  3.13    0.002793           0    400002           accept4
  1.80    0.001610           0    400002           recvfrom
  1.57    0.001400           0    400005           epoll_pwait
  1.33    0.001183           0    400003           epoll_ctl
```

Edit:
As suggested in the comment-section I tested again regarding memory-alignment ...

```
localhost:~# strace -e raw=recvfrom,writev ./test 
recvfrom(0x5, 0x7c7364ae2ee0, 0x800, 0, 0, 0) = 0x5d
writev(0x5, 0x7c7364ae1650, 0x1)        = 0x69

localhost:~# strace -f -e raw=recvfrom,writev /usr/sbin/nginx 
[pid  2381] recvfrom(0x3, 0x2344ebbd6a0, 0x800, 0, 0, 0) = 0x5d
[pid  2381] writev(0x3, 0x7df116c39f90, 0x1) = 0x86
```

Edit:
As requested the config of nginx:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
working_directory /var/www;

events {
    accept_mutex off;
    worker_connections 4096;
}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 8081;
        server_name "10.0.0.110";
        return 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare `strace -tt` output for both tests.

Comment: added the output of -tt

Comment: What does the test results timings from ab say ? Are your own code (which is much simpler than that of nginx) able to handle more requests/sec ? I would expect nginx to spend more CPU time internally and take a bit longer, lessening the momentary load on the OS(ksoftirqd).

Comment: That is actually the reason why I am asking this ... in a single threading context (so telling "ab" to just use one thread to generate the load) my code is faster (15.5k req/sec vs. 13k req/sec) which is totally as expected since nginx does actually parse the request :-). On the other hand with e.g. 4 threads nginx is faster (25k req/sec vs 32k req/sec) and I don't understand why.

Comment: [not the cause] `listen (servFd, 511);` I don;t think you need 511 here. Why?

Comment: I used 511 because since as you can see in the strace nginx uses 511 too.

Comment: If your code uses less total time than nginx to service the same number of requests, it's quite natural that ksoftirq uses more CPU, as it has more work to do per second, it just spends less total seconds to do it (i.e. if you spend 10 seconds of CPU time over 10 seconds, that's 100% CPU usage, if you spend those 10 seconds of CPU time over 20 seconds, that's 50% CPU usage). As for why nginx is faster when the tests are run in multi threaded, I don't know - nginx can be configured in numerous ways to take advantage of multiple cores , while your program does not.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear and address your points.

Comment: Have you tried using `perf record`? [Flame graphs](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) might be very helpful for this. If I remember correctly, nginx uses a master/follower thread pool. The master listens for new requests and offloads them to the followers, so it is a pretty lightweight multithreading model.

Comment: Ages ago it used this model even on linux. Not with threads but with processes. But since SO_REUSEPORT every worker can bind to the same port and the kernel does the load-balancing. But that is all besides the point ... if nginx did anything like it you would see it in the strace which I don't.

Comment: What are the compiler options for `nginx`?  Your `gcc -Wall test.c -o test` isn't going to do *any* optimizations,  I'd also check the alignment of the buffers both you and `nginx` pass to `recvfrom` and `writev`.  Also, is it safe to assume the servers are identical? I don't see any mention that the tests are run on the same server.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are correct ... I forgot to add the flag in this post but haven't while generating the numbers. My recv-buffer is on the stack so ... it shouldn't be a problem. Also this would not explain the high load of ksoftirqd. Yeah ... the server is the same. I ran both my test-application and nginx on the same server.

Comment: Just for fun I tested again without any optimisation and the difference is unnoticeable (which makes sense). Regarding your question about the compiler options of nginx ... I used the standard build that is shipped with the repo (I tested alpine and ubuntu btw)

Comment: @Xatian *My recv-buffer is on the stack so ... it shouldn't be a problem.*  Maybe, maybe not.  Your test code is getting interrupts that correspond to network activity, right?  Maybe your NIC likes to have buffers that are of a certain alignment? There's apparently *something* different in your userspace code from what `nginx` is doing that causes those interrupts, and memory alignment is easy to check.  The only difference I see is `nginx` has `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP)` to your `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP)`.  Maybe `SOCK_NONBLOCK` is it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle That makes sense ... how can I check memory alignment? I removed SOCK_CLOEXEC and SOCK_NONBLOCK from the accept socket ... makes no difference.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I added +1/+2/+3/+4 to the address of the recvBuffer when passing it to recvfrom ... makes no difference. (Did the same with writev as well). Is there something else to test regarding memory alignment?

Comment: Per [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), something like `strace -e raw=recvfrom|writev ...` should give you the raw values passed to those system calls.  I don't have access to a Linux system right now to test.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion ... I updated the question with the results.

Comment: What does your multithreaded code look like?  I'm wondering about CPU cache issues owing to page clashes...

Comment: @Xatian what is your nginx configuration?  Nginx often uses multiple threads, and your code is clearly running in only one.

Comment: @PeterBrittain Neither the posted code nor nginx is running any multithreaded stuff.

Comment: @cegfault strace would show the creation of any thread or process nginx could spawn. I don't see nginx spawning multiple threads and I configured nginx to spawn just one worker process (which you can see in the strace). So ... the event loop of nginx is equally single-threaded as is my test-code --> which is the point.

Comment: @Xatian a slight correction - if it spawns one worker process then nginx is using TWO threads - one to `accept()` (the main process, usually running as `root`), and the *second* thread to handle the connections.  This is very different from what you are doing; you are performing `accept()` and `recvfrom()` in the same thread.

Comment: In other words, when you say `I configured nginx to spawn .... ` then you're configuring nginx to **create** a thread, and you are not creating a thread, so it's very much possible there's a difference there.  If you post your nginx configuration, then I will be able to test on my systems and see what's going on.

Comment: @cegfault That is not true. Nginx uses a master/worker process model. The master does no work on incoming connections (it does not accept new connections) ... it just monitors the workers and spawns new ones in case one crashes or the admin reloads the config. The workers are doing the actual work and as you can see in the strace there is just one worker. The master does nothing after the worker is created. Furthermore you would see the creation of threads in the strace since a thread is created via the system-call clone --> I don't see any clone so there are no threads :-)

Comment: @cegfault Updated the post with a minimum config.

Comment: @xatian. Good question. I see that nginx is returning an HTTP/1.1 response, while the test code is returning an HTTP/1.0 response. That may be a confounding factor in the way the client operates. For instance, HTTP/1.1 can include keepalive- though I see ab is not being run with keepalive, still, there may be a different and less efficient code path involved. I would suggest returning *exactly* the same content and headers as nginx, and see if the results even out.

Comment: @JonahBenton Well ... yeah ... good point. I tested again by returning the exact same thing as nginx --> same result. I will update the question with the string I used. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: From the nginx traces, it looks like that nginx is doing 2 forks. Did you make sure that Nginx is having only one monitor process and only one worker. (And not 2 workers)

Comment: @Ritesh You are correct ... I think the first fork is to detach from the console since the main process exits soon after the first fork. (at 13:28:20.449046) Furthermore you can see when the strace goes on that a single worker (pid 2188) is doing all the work. If I throw more requests at it during the strace just this one process is working ... I haven't included that since the body of the question is limited.

Comment: Given that nginx is able to consume 99% of a cpu, along with the ksoftirq findings, might try binding your app to a core and preventing that core from servicing interrupts. I also see the use of FIONBIO and some signal masking. Maybe worth doing the same.

Comment: I see a significant time differences in last 3 syscalls. recvfrom, writev, and close. For the case of nginx , the time diff is 217 usec and 140 usec, but for the testcode, the difference become, 1002 usec and 2372 usec.

Comment: I also see difference in epoll_pwait arguments

Comment: I fiddled with this code a bit. I was able to replicate OP's finding- this code is faster than nginx with a single client or small number of clients, but nginx- even running in foreground- is faster with a large number of concurrent clients. There is a huge difference in context switch numbers- nginx requires only about 60% of the context switches. I have blocked signals, added cpu affinity, added more non-blocking io hints, reordered the code to get as much as possible out of the hot path, but have not been able to reproduce nginx's low context switch numbers.

Comment: @JonahBenton Wow thank you! How do you know about the context switches? How do you measure that? Do you also see the high ksoftirqd load?

Comment: @JonahBenton I believe the context switches are because of ksoftirqd running on the same core as the application forcing it to switch. As far as I understand it this process is per CPU and does some network-related stuff in kernel-space. It does less work when nginx is running so therefore nginx is getting more CPU-time and is therefore faster. But this is where my ideas end ... I don't know how to find out what ksoftirqd is doing or at least confirm this hypothesis ... so it could be totally unrelated :-)

Comment: Context switches- watching the reporting by vmstat 1 (which is systemwide). Systemwide interrupt and context switch counts are significantly higher with ./test than with /usr/sbin/nginx when handling the same workload. I don't think ksoftirq is a cause, it's more of an effect, of the higher interrupt count. Something nginx is doing is reducing the system cost of handling requests.

Comment: I'm seeing different results using hey instead of ab: https://github.com/rakyll/hey. In testing under hey, performance is difficult to distinguish between the code above and nginx at varying levels of concurrency. In looking closer at the results for ab, I'm also seeing some anomalies that lead me to believe it may have some subtle concurrency problems in its accounting. That's unexpected because I have used it for years. I will try to look deeper and write something up.

Comment: There is also an interesting result in that nginx produces only 60% as many voluntary context switches as the code above- as reported through /proc/$pid/status- but i think this has to do with the way that nginx' event loop works- http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#event_loop. It maintains its own timers, which, if in userspace, will result in many fewer calls to epoll_wait, and thus many fewer context switches.

Comment: @JonahBenton since you suspect that ab has something to do with the difference I wrote a small load-generator app (same style as the test-application in my question) --> produces the exact same result as ab.

Comment: @JonahBenton I can't follow with what you said about the user space-timers. Why does this reduce the number of calls to epoll_wait? It should reduce the number of calls to clock_gettime and family but not the number of epoll_wait calls. BTW --> in my second edit I traced with "-c" where you get a summary. In the result you can see that nginx does the same number of epoll_wait calls as the test-application.

Comment: About the memory alignment, sometimes to get a better performance with some buffers is good if they are aligned on cache line boundaries (because of DMA transfers). If I am not mistake the alignment for cache line on x86 architecture is 64 bytes. If you are using the stack, try **__attribute__ ((aligned (64)));** for your buffers (I am not sure if it works for 64 bytes). https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html Have a look to the linker documentation, this alignment could depend on it. Maybe it could help to get a better result.

Comment: Sometimes slower is faster. When you generate requests from many clients the epoll_wait can return multiple events at a time. If your code is fast the event count will be low or even just 1 and you soon end up doing another epoll_wait syscall. On the other hand if your code is slow then the event count will be higher. You then handle many requests before doing another epoll_wait syscall. And doing many requests takes time so more events have collected for the next epoll_wait call.  Compare the results for epoll_wait in both cases to see how many events per call both cases have.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You can see in the first edit that both my test-application and nginx both do 40k epoll_wait calls for 40k requests ... so no ... this is not what is happening. But you are close ... I actually solved the mystery already but haven't had time to answer my own question. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: If not already mentioned: To avoid alignment to affect your tests be sure to turn off address space randomization and use `env -i`. Something as simple as `export CFLAGS=-O2 -W -Wall` changes alignment and can have more effect than switching between -O2 and -O3.

Comment: @Xatian What was the explanation for this?

Comment: Thank you @JonahBenton and to anyone else who ran the code and helped me solve this mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer:
Sometimes being faster means being slower.

---

The long answer:

In a single-request setting (one request at a time) `epoll_wait` always blocks and forces a context-switch. The client (`ab` in this case) has to receive and process the response + send the next request before the server is woke up again and `epoll_wait` returns the pending socket. The speed in which the server generates the response does not change this behaviour since the client always waits for the server to respond before sending the next request.

In a multi-request setting it depends on the performance of the server if `epoll_wait` forces a context-switch or not. If the server-application is slower the chance of there being the next request already waiting is higher; in which case no  context switch is necessary since `epoll_wait` can return immediately. A context-switch is expensive and may take longer than it takes the next request to arrive wasting time.

I realised this when I eliminated the chance of `epoll_wait` making a context-switch by setting the timeout to zero. This forces `epoll_wait` to return immediately even if there is no pending request (so it never waits and therefore there is no forced context-switch). In this case the test-application way outperforms nginx even in a multi-request setting.

I further confirmed my theory by:

- **removing work** from nginx (disabling the access-log) which **made it slower**
- **adding work** to the test-application (spin-loop) which **made it faster**

in a multi-request setting.

---

For this answer I retook all measurements. All tests were ran on an updated ubuntu-box with 8 cores (so more than 5) with the server and the client running on this machine at the same time. The test-application is unchanged.

- gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
- nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

I wrote a small script to come up with the request/second number below that runs `ab` with 60.000 requests 100 times picking the fastest outcome.

```
maxRequests=0
for ((i = 0; i < 100; ++i)); do
    requests=$(ab -n 60000 -c (1 or 4) http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html 2>&1 | grep "Requests per second" | cut -d" " -f7)
    requests=${requests%.*}
    maxRequests=$(( maxRequests > requests ? maxRequests : requests ))
done
echo ${maxRequests}
```

---

Here again the base-values with the same settings like in the question.

```
Requests per second: 13507 (test-application, 1c)
Requests per second: 27648 (test-application, 4c)
Requests per second: 11755 (nginx, 1c)
Requests per second: 31446 (nginx, 4c)
```

To make nginx faster (and therefore slower with 4c) I disabled the access-log.

```
Requests per second: 12028 (nginx, 1c, no access-log)
Requests per second: 28976 (nginx, 4c, no access-log)
```

Here is the result if the test-application never sleeps by settings the `epool_wait` - time to zero.

Whats interesting is the difference in the 1c setting showing how much it costs to wake up the test-application when a new request arrives.

```
Requests per second: 20079 (test-application, 1c, spinning)
Requests per second: 34522 (test-application, 4c, spinning)
```

For these last measurements I added some work to the test-application making it artificially slower to increase the chance of preventing a context-switch. I added the code below to the end of the inner for-loop (after the `close`) and varied the initial value of `j` to get to the different results

```
uint8_t j = 50;
while (--j != 0) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while (--i != 0)
        asm("");
}
```

```
Requests per second: 12910 (test-application, 1c, j=50)
Requests per second: 12126 (test-application, 1c, j=100)
Requests per second: 11634 (test-application, 1c, j=150)
Requests per second: 11020 (test-application, 1c, j=200)
Requests per second: 10235 (test-application, 1c, j=250)
Requests per second: 27447 (test-application, 4c, j=25)
Requests per second: 29464 (test-application, 4c, j=50)
Requests per second: 31334 (test-application, 4c, j=75)
Requests per second: 32079 (test-application, 4c, j=100)
Requests per second: 33510 (test-application, 4c, j=125)
Requests per second: 34241 (test-application, 4c, j=150)
Requests per second: 34189 (test-application, 4c, j=175)
Requests per second: 33855 (test-application, 4c, j=200)
Requests per second: 33328 (test-application, 4c, j=250)
```

Comment: Solid analysis!